# JavaFX web deployment: FXMLLoader NullPointerException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I wanted to try JavaFX web browser deployment, so I started a very simple test project using the IntelliJ community edition 14.0.2 JavaFX Application template. Here's the code: (**NO** plugin, external library or maven)

Main.java

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Controller.java (attached to sample.fxml)

```
@FXML
private TextField textField;

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private void setLabelText() {
    label.setText(textField.getText());
}
```

sample.fxml (Layout file)

```
<VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
      prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
   </padding>
   <TextField fx:id="textField" onAction="#setLabelText"/>
   <Label fx:id="label" text="Label">
      <font>
         <Font size="96.0"/>
      </font>
   </Label>
</VBox>
```

Now when I build the app as JAR, it runs without any problem.
However, when I build it using the pre-defined "JavaFXApp" artifact, it generates one html, one jnlp and one jar. When I open up the html in my web browser (Firefox Nightly 64bit) It gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1838209255.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1604839423.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/982109627.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at com.sun.javafx.applet.FXApplet2$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1838209255.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1604839423.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/982109627.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    ... 11 more
```

The relevant line of code seems to be

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

However this same line of code works just fine when built and opened as single standalone JAR!
Any idea on why the error occurs or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error is somewhat cryptic, but understandable. you are getting a nullpointer with the localized message "Location is required", wich indicates that you did not set a location to find the FXML.

getClass().getResource("sample.fxml") returns null, and therefore the FXMLLoader throws a nullpointer. Check the path of your fxml, you might want to prepend it with a '/', like "/sample.fxml".

Comment: That didn't fix the problem :( As I said in the original post, the standalone JAR works just fine, even wiithout prepending "/". It's just the JavaFX artifact that throws the error...

Comment: Then it looks like a classpath problem, you could examine the jar contents and see if sample.fxml is in it?